# What's the meaning of "boredom-banishing"?

Tags: word-meaning

I was reading a book about language learning and I saw this sentence *"The world has shrunk further. Contacts with foreigners are no longer the privilege of professional diplomats, merchants seeking new markets, or **boredom-banishing** globetrotters."*

I searched everywhere and didn't find an answer to this. I tried to guess the meaning by analyzing each word "boredom" and "banishing"; by that, I came to a possible answer, boredom-banishing is someone who doesn't want to be bored and search for fun traveling, but I'm not convinced by this answer at all. Does anyone know this word?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you for the answer! I wasn't confident with my guess, I think I should be more confident with myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a "nonce-word" - made up on the spot for the specific context. But it's such an obvious one it will probably have been "re-coined" several times over the years. With the meaning OP already worked out - *someone who seeks to avoid being bored by globetrotting / traveling the world.*

You won't find [sleep-banishing](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+sleep-banishing%22) or [hunger-banishing](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+hunger-banishing%22) or [fear-banishing](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+fear-banishing%22) in the dictionary either, but they've all been used in print several times.